# Use Current Lync Session with UCWA

Tags: lync, skype-for-business, ucwa

I'm getting started with create a UCWA app and all the samples I see require the user to login.  All of my users will be running Lync or Skype for Business already.  Can my web app use this so I don't have to require them to login again?

-mike

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in taking a look at [GettingStarted-Authentication](http://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/GettingStarted-Authentication) and [KeyTasks-CreateApplication](http://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/KeyTasks-CreateApplication) to get a better idea of how authentication would work.  The desktop application does not provide a mechanism to expose their credential information that would be meaningful to UCWA.  You could look into urn:microsoft.rtc:passive authentication, but it is a bit more complex and would require making use of [Active Directory Federation Services (AD FS) 2.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd727958(WS.10).aspx).